# Java - Multiple components above the other (GUI)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I want to make a JFrame with multiple components above the other - it should look like this:

[image]

- Everything centered
- GridLayout scrollable *(if x is a huge number)*

What Layout should I use? How do I keep it as minimal as possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really give enough information, but what you give looks like BorderLayout to me -- image in the NORTH section, GridLayout in the CENTER, and a panel with your Label, TextField, and Button in the SOUTH.  The CENTER will shrink and grow with the size of the frame.  The bottom panel appears to have a BoxLayout with y-axis, and you can set x-axis centering on each component.

Comment: The bottom panel can be `GridLayout(3,1)` maybe.

Comment: Yes, the only problem is that the GridLayout in the CENTER is not scrollable - how do I fix that?

Comment: Put the GridLayout in a JPanel, and put the JPanel in a ScrollPanel

Comment: View the java documentation for a JScrollPane - basically, if the panel contained within the JScrollPane contains things that make it larger than the size set for the JScrollPane, it lets you scroll accordingly.